# Free Typescript plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, typescript, plugins

It is 2017 today, typescript language popularity is ramping, and I am not able to find a good eclipse plugin that fully supports typescript.

I have tested two that look promising, but they both are still not really ready to be used:

- TypeScript / Webclipse from genuitec: Works pretty good, but it requires a commercial license.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-0

- Palantir typescript plugin: Totally free, but fails to detect latest typescript syntax, and has a bug that shows a blank window when opening the compare editor with typescript files. It also looks like is not maintained anymore.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript

Anybody knows a good tool to use with ts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-nodejs-angular-json-yaml) plugin is useful for any kind of web application development.

> Simple and rich edition of typical main web and configuration files
>   (HTML, CSS, JS, TS, JSON, YAML, XML -with schema support-) and
>   debugging of Node.js apps in the Eclipse IDE. To see it in action,
>   open the desired file with the Generic Editor that's included by
>   default in the Eclipse IDE.
>
> - Supported file formats for edition:
>
>   HTML
>         CSS, SCSS, SASS, LESS
>         JavaScript (EcmaScript 2018 - 9th edition)
>         TypeScript 3.3
>         JSON and JSONC (including schema support)
>         YAML (including schema support, Kubernetes schema built-in)
>         XML (including schema support), XSL, XSD, DTD
> - Supported frameworks (file specialization) for edition:
>
>   Kubernetes
>     Angular (Components in TypeScript files)
>     React (JSX, TSX, embedded HTML)
> - Supported feature for edition are
>
>   Validation (diagnostics, markers)
>     Code Completion
>     Hover
>     Outline
>     Rename refactoring
>     Jump to declaration
>     Find references
>     Color preview
>     ... and other features part of the Language Server Protocol
> - Supported debugging target
>
>   Node.js
>     Firefox

Answer (score 12):

Answering my own question, I found a plugin that is totally free and works awesome:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-ide

It uses the same syntax coloring as javascript, and autocompletion works wonderfully.

Great work guys!!!!

EDIT: Wild web developer is the way to go now